# Get Blackberry Owner details (eg name/number) through API

Tags: blackberry

I know this is a simple one, but I'm not sure the name of the framework item that will help me. (I know Google could solve this one but my keyworks fail me)

I'm trying to gather some of the BlackBerry owner's details (phone number, first/last name, edit: email address) to autofill a "Create new account" screen.

I'm using DeviceInfo to return the DeviceId, but unsure how to retrieve owner contact details.

Comment: Looks like Session.getDefaultInstance().getServiceConfiguration().getEmailAddress() will get their email address.

Comment: Seems like your comment is the only correct answer. Please post it and accept it.

Comment: Ty, but the problem is, getting the email is only part of the question. Getting the BB owner's details is still outstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the phone number:

```
String phoneNum = net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone.getDevicePhoneNumber(false);
```

To get the Owner's name:

```
String owner = net.rim.device.api.system.OwnerInfo.getOwnerName();
```